# Error Integrating PayPal into Lightbox

Tags: javascript, paypal, lightbox

I am integrating a PayPal "Add to Cart" button into Lightbox 2.

With the help from some kind folks on this site, I was able to get the PayPal button implemented the way I wanted.

However, the problem I have now is, when you click the PayPal Add to Cart button, the PayPal shopping cart reports the following error:

> PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.

If I place the PayPal code directly in an HTML file, I don't get the error.

You can see a sample of this custom Add to Card button I implemented by clicking on the first (upper-left) photo on [this page](http://lancemissionart.com/index.php?Page=gallery&title=fof&gallery=msd).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using JS to make a request to PP ... if so, sounds like an authentication issue such as SSL or Cookies.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's using JS specifically to make the request to PayPal. I'm placing the PayPal code in the HTML. However, ultimately the PayPal Add to Cart button is place in JS based Lightbox window.

So you bring up a good point. Any suggestions on how I can check this and or change the authentication?

Comment: I looked at the source of your site. You have a mixture of both jQuery and Prototype. As well as both the Thickbox and the lightbox plugins. My assumption is that you duck-taped together sample code from lots of different places. My recommendation is create a simplified page with jQuery and Thickbox alone to isolate where the problem lies, if you cannot figure it out, post that simplified code.

Comment: Thanks. Problem SOLVED!!

The encode I placed into my HTML was incorrect...